# Associate for 100 rep

Tags: support, user-accounts, reputation

If I remember correctly associating your account on any stackexchange site should get you 100 reputation straight away to "get you started".

I've convinced a friend of mine to start using gamedev.stackexchange, however he only has 1 rep which he's finding annoying because he wants to comment on other peoples answers.

Is the 100 "start up" rep no longer in effect, or does he not have enough stackoverflow reputation to trigger it, or is this a bug of some kind?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/244179/aphid

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/4399/aphid

Nb. I'm asking this and not him, because he doesn't have the rep to participate in meta yet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a minimum of +200 rep in the network to get the +100 bonus, and your friend does not yet have that.

Note that to get the association bonus you will have to unassociate and re-associate later.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Jeff. I'll go and prod him into answering more questions ;)